# Summary Query to Sum Operations not working

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

```
SELECT price,total_price,SUM(mount) As TotalAmount
  FROM sales
  group by [date]
```

is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Try to learn `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: not ur business answer or non @bjan

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select fields in the SELECT part which is not a part of an Aggregated function or specified in the the GROUP BY clause when using GROUP BY.

You can select "`mount`" because it's aggregated (`SUM`), but not `price` or `total_price` because they're not aggregated nor part of your `group by date`

You will need to either change your group by functionality, or the select part.

Comment: i am selecting mount bro not price or total_price

Comment: You are selecting both price and total_price as well as "mount": SELECT *price*,*total_price*,SUM(mount)

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by the remaining tables that are not a function, therefore:

```
      SELECT price,total_price,SUM(mount) As TotalAmount
      FROM sales
      Group by price,total_price 
      Order by date
```

Comment: i need this operations grouped by date (for each date )